# how to instantiate another class using local variable?

Tags: flutter, class, dart

```
#how to instantiate another class using local variable in dart? #
```

==========================================================================

### How can I use myStatus variable to instantiate ToDoList class

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var myStatus = "Done";
  List<ToDoList> todoText = [
    ToDoList("hello", "Hello body", myStatus),
  ];
```

Comment: The instance member 'myStatus' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.=> vscode response

Comment: `myStatus` is not a *local* variable.  Local variables are declared within a function.  `myStatus` is an *instance* variable.